# Inset Border Radius with CSS

Tags: html, border-radius

I'd like to have the `border-radius` of the box inset.

I tried `border-right-bottom-radius: -100px` but it doesn't work

```html
<div style="max-width: 850px; height: 850px; background-color: #FBF6E9; padding: 10px; border-right-bottom-radius: -100px;">
</div>
```

This is what I would like:
[image: what i need]

Comment: I guess you want to have seperate `div` for the round corners. 

Comment: So, basically you want the `border-radius` to affect the inside of the border, instead of the outside of box?

Comment: @disinfor Yes, that's it ! Can `border-radius` be like what I want ?

Comment: @Alis OK! I changed the title and some of the wording of your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @deEr. no need for several separate elements :)

Comment: @disinfor I see, Your answer does produce something like additional elements too though. 

Comment: @deEr. I only meant separate `divs`. You do need to have something else, if you want the cut out to overlay content. You do not need anything separate if you don't. I'm going to add that example!

Comment: Prove https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/o246ty9j/2/ For whatever . @disinfor

Comment: Oh, I know you can do it with other `divs`, and it's a valid solution, but the question is can you do it with CSS alone, and you sure can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient) background on a `pseduo` element for this.

You have your main `container` which has the border, then you set a several `radial-gradient` circles on each corner of the pseudo `::before` element.

You can set the `radial-gradient` on the main container, however, any content will overlay the top of the circles. Using a `::before` with a higher `z-index` will "mask" any content in the container.

```css
:root {
 --radius-size: 20px;
 --border-color: purple;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 50px solid #FBF6E9;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: 
      radial-gradient(50px at top left, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(50px at top right, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(50px at bottom left, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(50px at bottom right, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent);
  z-index: 10;
}


/* FOR FUN CODE */
.container-no-pseudo {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background: 
      radial-gradient(50px at top left, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(50px at top right, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(50px at bottom left, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(50px at bottom right, #FBF6E9 99%, transparent);
  border: 50px solid #FBF6E9;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}


.container-vars {
  height: 500px;
  background: transparent;
  border: var(--radius-size) solid var(--border-color);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}


.container-vars::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: 
      radial-gradient(var(--radius-size) at top left, var(--border-color) 97%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(var(--radius-size) at top right, var(--border-color) 97%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(var(--radius-size) at bottom left, var(--border-color) 97%, transparent), 
      radial-gradient(var(--radius-size) at bottom right, var(--border-color) 97%, transparent);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>


<div class="container">
<h1>To demonstrate the "mask" if content is in this box.</h1>

<h5>Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam. Consequat luctus tempus.</h5>

Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo. Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper.
</div>


<div class="container-no-pseudo">
<h1>To demonstrate if there is not a pseudo element and the "corners" are the background of th container. </h1>

<h5>Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam. Consequat luctus tempus.</h5>

Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo. Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper.
</div>



<div class="container-vars">
<h1>To demonstrate using CSS vars to change all border and circle radius sizes at once.</h1>

<h5>Pharetra eros mi eros accumsan dui. Pellentesque ipsum iaculis. Mi neque in nonummy venenatis vestibulum. Class egestas adipiscing nisl tellus quam ut in amet. Nostra nunc leo lorem eget ipsum elit eget metus nam sed pede. Nam nibh risus sit dui nullam. Consequat luctus tempus.</h5>

Pede tellus eu mattis morbi donec. Natoque class leo. Ac lacus vestibulum ac odio ac. Risus lorem mauris. Proin enim tortor at erat dui. Aliquam magna condimentum. Orci donec morbi. Id justo at malesuada erat nulla urna quam eu nec elit commodo mi voluptatum gravida ante bibendum justo. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Phasellus malesuada adipiscing qui et eu. Justo egestas erat auctor sagittis sed nonummy amet dolor et in id. Ut blandit justo. Donec fringilla cursus enim velit ullamcorper.
</div>
```